# How to open server port on RHEL 6.6?

Tags: rhel, firewall

I am trying to open a port (tcp 27017) for access to mongodb on a newly created RHEL 6.6 instance at Amazon AWS.  Following mongo docs, I did:

```
sudo semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017
```

I also opened that port on the Amazon security group.  But, I still get connection failure.  I found a handy tip somewhere to test whether a port is reachable using:

```
curl http://address:port
```

If I use 127.0.0.1:27017 on the box, I get back a message like "Looks like you are trying to access a mongo server".  If I instead plug in the host private IP address, or do it from another host, I get "Could not connect".  If I repeat using port 22, I get SSH version echo.

When I do `sudo iptables -L` it comes back with headings for INPUT/FORWARD/OUTPUT but no rules are displayed.  Yet, I found in /etc/sysconfig/iptables where port 22 was being explicitly authorized.  So I edited that file, duplicated that line, and did a reboot.  That had not effect.

Any suggestions what is going on?  I had been using ubuntu server, but for no particular reason, so I thought I would switch to Red Hat, but maybe a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, default /etc/mongod.conf is configured with `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`.  Commenting that out fixes problem.  Duh.